# How can you have French-Canadian localization for PayPal Standard?

Tags: localization, paypal

As far as I can tell, PayPal limits language localizations based on country code. For Canada, it appears that only English is supported. This is a big problem given that somewhere between 1/5 and 1/4 of Canadians speak French as their primary language.

So here is my issue:

In my donation form I have a hidden field for language code (lc). I can optionally set the country code to Canada (CA); however, this is not required as my account is Canadian.

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="FR">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="CA">
...
```

When a user submits this form, even with PayPal cookies cleared from their browser, they are taken to an English-language version of the payment form.

The really astounding thing, is that when I visit PayPal from Canada, it gives me the option to display the site in French or English. So clearly they are aware that there are French and English speakers in Canada. I can even use this toggle to display the payment form in French. There is indeed a French-Canadian localization of the form. There is just no configure PayPal to show this. Instead user interaction is required.

Changing the country code is the only way I can programmatically get the form to display in French. However, this is unacceptable as it does other localizations (such as available payment options) that do not apply for Canadians.

Is there any way to work around this and programmatically trigger the display of a the French-Canadian version of the payment form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="fr_CA">
```

The language could change after the user logs into his/her PayPal account, but that would be expected (and desired), but I assume you're aware of that.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that has the effect of setting the country to France. I'd prefer a solution that keeps the country as Canada.

Comment: But replacing the FR with CA (fr_CA) did. Looks like PayPal needs to update their documentation. Cheers.

Comment: Woops, that's what I meant. Yes, we're going to update these documents shortly.